# fwmark routing policy with netplan

Tags: networking, iptables, 18.04, routing, netplan

I'm migrating a legacy Debian setup to a new Ubuntu setup. I have previously set, in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
post-up /sbin/ip rule add fwmark 1 table table.tunnel
pre-down /sbin/ip rule del fwmark 1 table table.tunnel
```

Now that I'm on Ubuntu, it looks like I need to use netplan and the routing-policy section. Specifically, I think I should be able to use:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
eno1:
  dhcp4: yes
  dhcp6: yes
  routing-policy:
   - table: 201
     fwmark: 1
```

Where table.tunnel is 201 in `/etc/iproute2/rt_table`. I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, as fwmark isn't documented as available in the netplan version included in 17.10.

When I try and apply the configuration, I get the error:

```
The overwriting error message was: Error in network definition 
//etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml 
  line 10 column 7: IP routing policy must include either a 'from' or 'to' IP
Error in network definition //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
  line 10 column 9: unknown key fwmark
```

It seems incorrect that I need to have a to/from in routing-policy (rather than routing) and this is suggested in man page:

```
routes (mapping)
          The  routes  block  defines  standard  static  routes   for   an
          interface.  At least to and via must be specified.
....
routing-policy (mapping)
          The  routing-policy  block  defines  extra  routing policy for a
          network, where traffic may be handled  specially  based  on  the
          source IP, firewall marking, etc.
```

Even if I put in a random to address, it still throws up the unknown key fwmark (even though this is stated in the man page).

Anyone got any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a bug in netplan.  I have reported this as an upstream bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1767955

Comment: Thanks. Changing the key 'fwmark' to 'mark' in the configuration is now accepted. It was also necessary to set "to: 0.0.0.0/0" and create a second entry for "to: ::/0" for IPv6 and my rules are working correctly.